# I can't run Espresso test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have problem with espresso tests. When the tests starts I always get this:
Started running tests
Test running failed:

> Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'
>
> Empty test suite.

I've restarted, cleaned, rebuilt project and is still same. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.daniellachacz.taskmvvm"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

//Livedata
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

//Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1"

//FloatingActionButton
implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'

//RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

//Espresso
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

}
```

TestClass:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
 public class MainScreenTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void floatingActionButton() {
    onView(withId(R.id.floating_action_button))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're starting the right test class?

Comment: It was very good question. I had bad AndroidJUnit4.class.

Comment: Try the following: go to Run - Edit configurations... Remove your test class from the list in the left panel and start the test again.

Comment: @Psytho
Thank you but it's unnecessary. I changed few dependencies and it works.